# how to use datatable with dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jsp, datatables

I have a jsp which onload calls a js in which a table is created dynamically.
The situation is that I have never worked on jquery earlier, all I know is javascript.

I made two scenarios:

case one : when I create static table on the jsp page itself it works flawlessly.
case two : when I try to load the same table which is created by dynamic javascript it fails.

Case I  Working code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
<script  src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/createDynamicTable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#testTable').dataTable();
}); 

</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="tableDataDiv">
<table id="testTable">
<thead>                   
<th>h1</th>
<th>h2</th>
<th>h3</th>                   
</thead>


<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Case II  Not Working code

jsp code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
<script  src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/createDynamicTable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#testTable').dataTable();
}); 

</script>
</head>
<body onload="getTableData();">


<div id="tableDataDiv">

</div>
</body>
</html>


js code

function getTableData(){

var tableDataDivObj = document.getElementById("tableDataDiv");

var tableObj = document.createElement("table");
tableObj.id = 'testTable';

// header
var theadObj = document.createElement("thead");

var thObj = document.createElement("th");
thObj.innerHTML = 'h1';
theadObj.appendChild(thObj);

thObj = document.createElement("th");
thObj.innerHTML = 'h2';
theadObj.appendChild(thObj);

thObj = document.createElement("th");
thObj.innerHTML = 'h3';
theadObj.appendChild(thObj);

tableObj.appendChild(theadObj);

// body
var tbodyObj;
var trObj;
var tdObj;
tbodyObj = document.createElement("tbody");

var count = 1;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
trObj = document.createElement("tr");

for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
tdObj = document.createElement("td");
tdObj.innerHTML = count;
trObj.appendChild(tdObj);
count++;
}

tbodyObj.appendChild(trObj);
}


tableObj.appendChild(tbodyObj);

tableDataDivObj.appendChild(tableObj);
}
```

Once the table is created dynamically, we append it to the div on the jsp page.

Kindly suggest any modification, suggestions so that I can get this code work.
this is just an example I have created of my real application .
which involves complete mvc, where table data is retrived from the service methods and dao files. I am able to get the data into the table(I made sure after getting an alert on jsp page). I am not able to use datatable on the id of the table.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

When your dataTables initialization is run, the table doesn't exist yes.  You can fix by moving the `$('#testTable').dataTable();` after the table has been initialized.

```
$(tableObj).dataTable();
```

at the end of the `getTableData` function (which should be defined in your `$(document).ready` callback.

Comment: so this is what I have done as per the suggestion:
I moved the calling code from jsp page to js page right after the table is created.

tableObj.appendChild(tbodyObj);
tableDataDivObj.appendChild(tableObj);
$('#testTable').dataTable();

I however got the following javascript error now:
 aaSorting is null or not an object
kindly guide what to do now.

Comment: on the jsp, i now call my method getTableData() inside document.ready function,..I think this is equivalent to calling my method onload=getTableData() on html...So still got the same result aaSorting is null or not an object.

Answer (score 2):

Yon can add datatable to your dynamically created table in javascript.Code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
function createTable(){

var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("box");
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
table.id='tableId'
table.border='1';

var header = table.createTHead();
var row = header.insertRow(0);
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
cell.innerHTML = "<b>Name</b>";
cell1.innerHTML = "<b>Age</b>";
cell2.innerHTML = "<b>Email</b>";
cell3.innerHTML = "<b>address</b>";

var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);

for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
var tr = document.createElement('TR');
tableBody.appendChild(tr);

for (var j=0; j<4; j++){
   var td = document.createElement('TD');
   td.width='75';
   td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + i + "," + j));
   tr.appendChild(td);
}
}
myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
$("#tableId").dataTable();
}
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="createTable();" value="CreateTable" /></br>
<div id="box">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please call jquery method once your table get created by dynamic javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can find example here how to create dynamically:
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: The linked example is for a DOM which already has a table statically defined. The question is about an undefined table, created on the fly.